# Нужны ли запятые в конструкции типа "ст. 2, ч. 1, п. 5"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Внести изменения в ст. 2, ч. 1, пункт 5. Т.е. в пункт 5 части 1 статьи 2. А если с предлогами: в ст. 2 в ч. 1 в п. 5? При обратном порядке изложения позиций. Хотелось бы ссылку на какое-нибудь правило

Answer (score 3):

Правила таковы:

При необходимости дать ссылку не на весь правовой акт, а только на его структурную единицу сначала указывается эта конкретная единица (начиная с наименьшей).
Пример:
«регулируются пунктом 4 части 2 статьи 10 Федерального закона от......... №... «............»

https://studfiles.net/preview/5866402/page:5/

При обратном порядке запятые нужны, потому что там идёт перечень структурных единиц, но правила делопроизводства  всё-таки диктуют полное наименование единиц (слов пункт, часть) во избежание неверного понимания, и начинать следует  с наименьшей. С предлогами вообще ни разу не видела оформления, наверно, это неправильно.